# React native implement Youtube data API v3

Tags: react-native, youtube-api, axios, youtube-data-api

Is it possible somehow to integrate youtube data API v3 directly in react-native?

If not, Is there any other way to do it?

Right now I am using **axios** to send get request but not able to figure out how exactly send the request what I tried is this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels', {
      params: {
        'id': 'UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw',
        'key': 'AIzaSy...',
        'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics'
      }
    }).then(
      (response) => {
        console.warn(response);
      }).catch(
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Not sure whether it is correct or not as I don't have much experience in React native. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the result of this code?

Comment: Warning saying result code 400

Comment: @TapanHP what do you want to do exactly? Fetch YouTube video?

Comment: Yes, I wanna fetch the list of videos from youtube channel and also I have some more things to do with data API like fetching channel list. @Eduard
The thing I am really confused about is which docs should I follow for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use packages like [youtube-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search) or [youtube-api-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-api-search)for your purpose.

The call with the latter one looks like this:

```
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
YTSearch({ key: YOUR_API_KEY, term: YOUR_SEARCH_STRING }, result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Eduard I will surely try this one and tell you how it works for me

Comment: @TapanHP no problem :)

Comment: I can confirm, as of Jan 30, 2018. youtube-api-search works with RN .49^. It was a simple plug and play